# How to pass variable from one browser window to the another browser window (Same browser) in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I don't want to display param in addressbar & don't wan't to store it locally.
For e.g. Param value like vndfj/dfgdgdfg12/dg==.

I have tried below code but it's not working on IE and edge

```
let data = {
  __tkn: "sjkss/sdfsdf/fdffs23=="
}

 let wObj = window.open('./Test');
 wObj .json_data = data;
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem.StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Let's clarify your question, are you trying to pass data from any browser to ie11? Or into same browser?

Comment: No. I'm trying in same browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with window.open property,

For example,

```
    printDocument() {
    //generate render link
    let printURL = this.apiBaseUrl + "WestCore/GuaranteeLetter/" + this.selectedDocumentId + "/RenderGuaranteeLetter?reportPath=" + encodeURIComponent(this.selectedTemplate);
    window.open(printURL);
  }
```

Or this is how i render blob images in my project using window.open...

```
  createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // FOR IE10+
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(image, "download." + (image.type.substr(image.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)));
    else {
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(image);
      window.open(url);
    }
  }
```